# How do I check if a radio button is checked using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

When I select a radio button then click the download button, nothing happens. No alert shows up or anything.

Here is my code right now:

HTML:

```
<form id="Resume_Select">
<input type="radio" name="resume_type" value="Economics" >Economics
<br />
<input type="radio" name="resume_type" value="MIS" >Management Information Systems
<br />
<button onClick="resume_select()"> Download</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function resume_select(){
    var radios = document.getElementByName('resume_type');
    for(var i = 0, length = radios.length; i<length;i++){

        if(radios[i].checked){
            var resume = radios[i].value;
            alert(radios[i].value);
            break;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: @TimRijckaert elaborate please. I took the loop from an answer I found for someone with the same question and that is the loop they used.

Comment: @TimRijckaert I'm assuming you mean the ", length..." Part? Because I was confused with that too. I never wrote a for loop that used a comma. But I just took the guys word. I'll change that back to a semicolon and then get the length variable before the loop starts. That would be better, correct?

Comment: The initialisation part of the `for` loop is valid. It's caching the length of the HTMLCollection rather than calculating it each iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `getElementsByName` plural not getElementByName. First thing that jumped at me.

Comment: You can simplify your loop like so: 
for(i = 0; i<radios.length; i++){ ... }

Comment: Okay, I will give that a try. Sounds like a simple enough fix.

Comment: will do! Just got home, so I am testing it now

Comment: That's because you have everything inside form tags. So two options remove them or create a input type button with the on click event attached to it. I noticed that issue when I tested your code on jsfiddle so instead of using a button use an input of type button

Comment: @atomCode took out the form tags. Still nothing. No alert.

Comment: You have yet another syntax error that's why. You should look at your code more closely, your function is not closed

Comment: @atomCode .....damn I am bad at this. Thank you so much for your help and understanding. It works now

Comment: You got it! I take it back it should still work with the form tags  the whole issue was the closing function bracket